# Как передать значение из ссылки в метод контролера

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

Как передать значение из ссылки в метод контроллера. Передаю через `asp-route-id` ID, но когда код выполняется в методе контролера `Show(long id)` `id = 0`, независимо какую страницу я не открываю. Как правильно передать параметр из ссылки в метод?

```
        @foreach(var f in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Show" asp-route-id="@f.Id">
                    @f.Name
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }



        public IActionResult Show(long a)
    {
        return View(repository.Film.Where(r=>r.Id==a));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы используете asp-route-id, то используйте вместе с ним `asp-controller` и `asp-action`. Без них ASP.NET Core не поймёт, куда передавать параметр.

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="5" >Item5</a>
```

Подробнее можно почитать в этой [статье](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/10.2.php) (пример взят также из неё).

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение!

```
        @foreach(var f in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(f.Name,"Show", new { id=f.Id})
                 @*f.Name- Имя будующей url,
                "Show" - Имя метода в конроллере,
                id - Передаваемый аргумент в метод Show(int id)*@
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

        public IActionResult Show(long id)
    {
        return View(repository.Film.Where(r=>r.Id==id));
    }
```

Comment: Если ваше решение и есть ответ на ваш вопрос, отметьте его как ответ к вопросу.